# How to restore iTunes DVD backup to v10.5

Tags: itunes

I had an old mac mini die on me, so new machine has itunes 10.5. I backed up the old machine itunes library on DVD, using the backup functionality in itunes. There is no restore from dvd option in 10.5. How do I recover my music ? This seems idiotic to not support restoring from dvd in the new product. Fine, get rid of backup, but at least allow restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open iTunes then select File > Add to Library. Select your files and click open.

You also should be able to put your Library in `/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music`. Or, just put the library somewhere in your `/Music` folder and select File > Preferences > Advanced (tab), then under iTunes Media folder location click Change, and find the folder that you have your library in.